# How can I make an old-fashioned HTML form submission that uses jQuery only for the callback(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Because my the totality of my page is a basic "name and email" registration form, I don't see why I can't do a good ole-fashioned

```
    <form action="/Account/Register/" method="POST" id="registration-form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" id="name" placeholder="Example input">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eaddr" id="email" placeholder="Another input">
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Take Survey</button>
    </form>
```

It seems like the definition of overengineering to do

```
$.ajax({
    url  : '/Account/Register',
  method : 'POST',
  data   : { pname : $('input[name="pname"]').val(),
             eaddr : $('input[name="eaddr"]').val() },
});
```

After all, that's what a `form` is for in the first place!

But I do want one thing from the submission of the `form` and that is `success` and `error` callbacks. Is there any way to submit that `form` in an HTML manner and still hook up callbacks? If so, how?

Comment: 6 lines of code is hardly over-engineering. Besides, you can trim it down using `$.serialize` (see jQuery docs) And you can't submit an html form without reloading the page unless you use ajax. If you do a plain-old html submit, the idea of error/success callbacks are kind of meaningless since they were redirected anyway.

Comment: An old fashioned form submit navigates the user to another page (or possibly to the same page, but refreshed). The success and error concept you want really doesn't apply to that. For traditional form submits if an error occurred the server-side code would return some kind of error page.

Comment: Either you submit the simple form and get a new page OR you Ajax it and get callbacks. If you want to submit without jQuery and without a reload,  you need to submit to a hidden iFrame and have the result modify the calling page with returned script.

Answer (score -2):

Use $.submit(), this is the way you can do it with jQuery. As the other commenters wrote, you either post & refresh the page or use ajax:

```
$("#registration-form").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url  : '/Account/Register',
    method : 'POST',
    data   : { pname : $('input[name="pname"]').val(),
             eaddr : $('input[name="eaddr"]').val() },
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function() {}
  });
  return false;
});
```